# Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estou tentando criar um `CRUD` simples de cadastro de categorias e subcategorias onde uma categoria pode ter várias subcategorias porém uma subcategoria pode ter apenas uma categoria. Em meu migrátion fiz minhas tabelas da seguinte maneira:

```
Schema::create('sub_categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('CdSubCategoria');
   $table->integer('CdCategoria')->unsigned()->index();
   $table->string('NmSubCategoria');
   $table->string('DscSubCategoria');
   $table->integer('FlgPontua');
   $table->integer('QtdPontos');
   $table->integer('MaxPontosPorSubCategoria');

   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();



    $table->foreign('CdCategoria')
          ->references('CdCategoria')
          ->on('categorias');
});
```

E minha tabela de categorias:

```
Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('CdCategoria');
   $table->string('NmCategoria', '50');
   $table->string('DscCategoria', '255');
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();

});
```

Ja em meu Model de categoria eu fiz:

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['CdCategoria','NmSubCategoria', 'DscSubCategoria', 'FlgPontua', 'QtdPontos', 'MaxPontosCategoria'];
protected $primaryKey = 'CdSubCategoria';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function categoria()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
}
```

E no de subCategorias:

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['NmCategoria', 'DscCategoria'];
protected $primaryKey = 'CdCategoria';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function subCategoria()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategoria');
}
```

Com isto tudo feito meu controller manda para uma view lisSubCategorias, onde quero listar as subcategorias e mostrar o nome da categoria pai dela,
desta forma:

```
$subCategoria->categoria->NmCategoria
```

Ao efetuar este comando juntamente com `dd()` é retornado para mim a página de erro descrevendo o erro:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: ...\views\SubCategoria\listSubCategoria.blade.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#introduction), existe um padrão nas chaves de relacionamentos, padrão esse não obrigatório, que é uma convenção de `nome de tabela`, `underscore` e `chave`, **exemplo**: `categoria_id`.

Como não ***foi seguido*** e ***não é obrigatório***, principalmente por bancos legados, o [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#introduction) pode ser configurado com os nomes de campos a sua maneira, só que isso implica em informar ao [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#introduction) quais são as chaves e nome de campos.

*Tradução*

**1:1**

```
$this->hasOne(relacao, chave estrangeira, primary key);
```

**N:1**

```
$this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação);
```

**1:N**

```
$this->hasMany(relação, chave estrangeira da relação, primary key local);
```

**N:N**

```
$this->belongsToMany('relacao', 'nome da tabela pivot', 'key ref. local model em pivot', 'key ref. relação em pivot')
```

Isso tudo só foi mesmo a introdução para solucionar o problema da pergunta, então, reconfigurando os relacionamentos, como explicado não segue a convenção precisa ser especificado no seu [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#introduction).

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = [
          'CdCategoria',
          'NmSubCategoria',
          'DscSubCategoria', 
          'FlgPontua', 
          'QtdPontos', 
          'MaxPontosCategoria'
      ];

protected $primaryKey = 'CdSubCategoria';

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function categoria()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','CdCategoria','CdCategoria');
}
```

---

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['NmCategoria', 'DscCategoria'];

protected $primaryKey = 'CdCategoria';

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function subCategoria()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategoria','CdCategoria','CdCategoria');
}
```

No seu caso especifico ficou fácil relacionar, muitas vezes as chaves tem nomes diferentes e causam um trabalho extra na configuração e manutenção de código.

Para buscar as informações do relacionamento utilize [with](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with)('nome_da_relacao->nome do método') para fazer a carga `eager loaded` da relação:

***Exemplo:***

```
$subCategoria = SubCategoria::with('categoria')->get();
```

e isso resume no código abaixo que precisa ser executado:

```
$subCategoria->categoria->NmCategoria
```

Comment: Você é genial ! Parabens