# Trying to get property 'nome' of non-object Laravel Eloquent Error ao puxar dados chave estrangeira

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade, chave-estrangeira, model

Estou tentando usar relacionamentos para mostrar dados na tela mas eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Trying to get property 'nome' of non-object

Neste comando

```
$recebimento->planoconta()->get()->first()->nome
```

**MODEL PLANO CONTA**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Planoconta extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'plano_contas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'tipo', 'nome', 
    ];

    public function pagamento():hasMany{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pagamento', 'plano_contas_id');
    }

    public function recebimento():hasMany{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Recebimento', 'plano_contas_id');
    }



}
```

**MODEL RECEBIMENTOS**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Cliente;
use Planoconta;

class Recebimento extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'recebimentos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'data_emissao','data_venci','documento','parcela', 'valor', 'cliente_id','plano_contas_id', 'descricao',
    ];

    public function cliente():BelongsTo{
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Cliente');

    }

    public function planoconta():BelongsTo{
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Planoconta');

    }


}
```

**HTML**

```
@foreach($recebimentos as $recebimento)
   <tr class="itemRecebimento{{$recebimento->id}}">
       <td>{{$recebimento->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$recebimento->data_receb}}</td>
       <td>{{$recebimento->valor}}</td>
       <td>{{$recebimento->cliente()->get()->first()->nome}}</td>
       <td>{{$recebimento->planoconta()->get()->first()->nome}}</td>                                
       <td><button class="btnOpenUpdateRecebimento btn btn-info" data-id="{{$recebimento->id}}" data-data_receb="{{$recebimento->data_receb}}" data-valor="{{$recebimento->valor}}" data-cliente_nome="{{$recebimento->cliente()->get()->first()->nome}}" data-cliente_id="{{$recebimento->cliente()->get()->first()->id}}" data-plano_contas="{{$recebimento->plano_contas}}" > <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button>
                                    <button class="delete-recebimento btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$recebimento->id}}" data-data_receb="{{$recebimento->data_receb}}" data-valor="{{$recebimento->valor}}" data-cliente_nome="{{$recebimento->cliente()->get()->first()->nome}}" data-cliente_id="{{$recebimento->cliente()->get()->first()->id}}" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
        </td>
       </tr>
   @endforeach
```

**MODEL CLIENTE QUE ESTA FUNCIONANDO E FIZ EXATAMENTE IGUAL**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasMany;
use Recebimento;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    ////
    protected $table = 'clientes';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'cpf', 'endereco', 'numero', 'cep', 'complemento', 'bairro', 'celular', 'telefone', 'cidade', 'estado', 'email',
    ];


    public function recebimento():hasMany{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Recebimento', 'cliente_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Até aqui deve esta retornando `null` -> `$recebimento->planoconta()->get()->first()` !!! procure saber o retorno antes de acessar a propriedade é esse problema.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Como devo prosseguir? No banco a relação esta funcionando, todos recebimentos estão cadastrado com plano de contas, não há por que retornar null

Comment: se não tiver resultado retorna null

Comment: dá um `var_dump($recebimento->planoconta()->get())` é verifica o que retorna

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Realmente, esta retornando NULL, mas não entendo por que!!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse resposta e siga as instrução: falta configuração porque você não deve ter feito na convenção correta: então tem que ser configurado item a item: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976 , mas como foi dito se não tiver dados retorna null mesmo

Comment: Outro post que explica item a item: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108

Comment: @VirgilioNovic 

segui esses passos

N:1

$this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação); 
1:N

$this->hasMany(relação, chave estrangeira da relação, primary key local);

public function planoconta():BelongsTo{
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Planoconta', 'id', 'id');

    }

 public function recebimento():hasMany{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Recebimento', 'plano_contas_id', 'id');
    }

e agora funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function recebimento():hasMany{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recebimento', 'plano_contas_id', 'id');
}

public function planoconta():BelongsTo{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Planoconta', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Importante sempre informar os campos!

Comment: Só é importante informar os campos quando não se segue a convenção!