# Como usar o Carregamento ansioso aninhado no Laravel 5.4 de forma correta? minhas tabelas relacionada retornam "null"

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Tenho a seguinte busca em minha aplicação:

`$results = Profile::with('profileCategories.categories', 'informations')->where('ativo', '=', "1")->where('nome', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')->orWhere('sobre', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')->orderBy('profile_type_id', 'ASC')->get();`

Onde tenho um relacionamento entre a tabela profiles, que possui varios profile_categories que também pertence a categories (relacionamento Many-to-Many). Ao executar recebo Collection:

```
Collection {#333 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Profile {#336 ▼
      +table: "profiles"
      +fillable: array:14 [▶]
      #casts: array:15 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:18 [▶]
      #original: array:18 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "profileCategories" => Collection {#337 ▼
          #items: array:3 [▼
            0 => ProfileCategory {#344 ▼
              +table: "profile_categories"
              +fillable: array:1 [▶]
              #casts: array:2 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:5 [▶]
              #original: array:5 [▶]
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #events: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "categories" => null
              ]
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            1 => ProfileCategory {#345 ▶}
            2 => ProfileCategory {#346 ▶}
          ]
        }
        "informations" => Collection {#339 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Minhas Models estão assim:

```
class ProfileCategory extends Model
{

    public $table = 'profile_categories';

    ...

    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Profile::class);
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Category::class);
    }


class Category extends Model
{

    public $table = 'categories';

    ...

    public function profileCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ProfileCategory::class);
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    public $table = 'profiles';

 ...

    public function profileCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ProfileCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Com isso recebo "categories" => null, como faço para que a busca receba os dados da categoria associada?

Comment: Possa ser as chaves que não estão no padrão que o Eloquent exige e se não estiver no padrão (convenção) tem que ser configurado, se poderia colocar o layout dessas tabelas e suas relações!? digo isso porque é assim mesmo que carrega as relações ! se não carrega pode ser configuração.

Comment: Alguns link Relacionamento 1:n: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108

Comment: Relacionamento - N:M https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376

Comment: @VirgilioNovic dei uma olhada nos links e a única coisa que está fora dos padrões é o nome da tabela, mas mesmo usando algo apra renomear não deu muito certo. Agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte maneira:

```
$results = Profile::rightJoin('informations', 'informations.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.id')
            ->join('profile_categories', 'profile_categories.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.id')
            ->rightJoin('categories', 'profile_categories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where('profiles.ativo', '=', "1")
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('profiles.nome', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('profiles.sobre', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('categories.descricao', '=', $request->search)
                    ->orWhere('informations.rua', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
            })
            ->orderBy('profiles.profile_type_id', 'ASC')
            ->select('profiles.id', 'profiles.nome', 'profiles.sobre', 'profiles.profile_type_id', 'informations.rua')->distinct()->get();
```

Agora posso realizar minha busca avaliando o nome, sobre, categorias e também pela rua nas informações.
De outra forma não consegui.