# Relacionar Tipo e Subtipo

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Como posso chamar um `Subtipo` buscando pelo `tipo_id`, fiz alguns testes aqui mas nenhum com sucesso esse é o meu primeiro projeto.

Tabela do Tipo

```
public $timestamps = true;
protected $table   = 'tipo';
protected $fillable = ['id','titulo'];
protected $hidden = [];

public function subtipo() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subtipo::class, 'tipo_id');
}
```

SubTipo

```
public $timestamps = true;
protected $table   = 'subtipo';
protected $fillable = ['id','tipo_id','titulo'];
protected $hidden = [];

public function ticket() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class, 'subtipo_id');
}

public function tipo() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tipo::class, 'tipo_id');
}
```

Vou criar um sistema de Ticket, e colocar o status de aberto , lido e fechado nos Tickets e precisava chamar esses 'subtipos' pelo tipo ticket (`id=1`)

Estava testando coisas desse tipo no `SubTipoRepository`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new SubTipo();
}


public function findByTipoTicket($tipo_id)
{
    return $this->model->where('tipo_id',1)->all();
}
```

Comment: `return $this->model->where('tipo_id',1)->all();` aqui deu algum erro? deveria `return $this->model->where('tipo_id',1)->get();`!

Comment: No seus modelos de classes se o `id` for ***chave primária*** e ***auto incremento*** não precisa colocar no `$fillable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel)